# Why did convert nchar(2) or nvarchar(10) to char(8)/varchar(40) automatically in ibm db2?

Tags: db2

I am converting mssql to db2.
nchar/nvarchar in mssql need to convert nchar/nvarchar in ibm db2.
but, All is same action for dbeaver tool, db2 console.
I need to convert nchar(n) and nvarchar(max) to db2 datatypes,
because of acceptable unicode.

plz, help me. thanks.

(I am using db2 docker image : ibmcom/db2:11.5.6.0a)

Answer (score 0):

It becomes to large for a comment, so I'll add some info to @Nuwans answer. There is actually more to it than - for example - VARCHAR(n). I assume you are using an UTF-8 enabled Db2 database.

What VARCHAR(n) means depends on the db cfg [STRING_UNIT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-string-units-default-string-units). If it's SYSTEM the n represents number of bytes (which becomes very cumbersome for determining length of a string as an example), Even if it is specified as SYSTEM you can still use multibyte characters by declaring your column as:

```
VARCHAR(n CODEUNITS32)
```

I found an old information that states that NVARCHAR(MAX) can hold `(2 ^ 31 - 1 - 2) / 2 = 1'073'741'822 double-byte characters`. I assume this has not decreased since and it is bigger than what can be stored in a VARCHAR, VARGRAPHIC or CLOB (in CODEUNITS32). See [sql-xml-limits](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sql-xml-limits), section String Limits. In that table you will also find:

```
Maximum length of DBCLOB (in double-byte characters or CODEUNITS16) 1,073,741,823
```

So your best choice for NVARCHAR(MAX) is probably:

```
DBCLOB(1073741823 CODEUNITS16)
```

GRAPHIC / VARGRAPHIC existed before UTF-8 in Db2 as a way to handle multi byte characters. These days it is probably better to use UTF-8 and STRING_UNITS =  CODEUNITS32